# Java - Pcap4j only detects host device's adress

Tags: java, networking, winpcap, jpcap, pcap4j

I've been trying to write a sniffer for ARP-packet detection. I've gotten the Pcap4j library to run and detect my network, but it only shows the computer that it's currently running on in the list of adresses. There are a lot of different devices connected to the network, Wireshark can detect them all. I've checked that at least the host computer and another one have detection set to open in the Windows settings and they can recognize each other in the Windows network.

This is the very rudimentary code:

```
package arpsniffer;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface;
import org.pcap4j.util.LinkLayerAddress;
import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

/**
 *
 * @author Fabio
 */
public class ArpSniffer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PcapNetworkInterface nif;
        try {
          nif = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
            for(LinkLayerAddress addr : nif.getLinkLayerAddresses()){
                System.out.println(addr.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output (Pcap4J opens a text dialogue to let me decide on the network device and I confirmed it is the right one!)

```
[main] INFO org.pcap4j.core.NativeMappings - Pcap4J successfully loaded a 

native pcap library: WinPcap version 4.1.3 (packet.dll version 4.1.0.2980), based on libpcap version 1.0 branch 1_0_rel0b (20091008)
[main] INFO org.pcap4j.util.PropertiesLoader - [org/pcap4j/pcap4j.properties] Could not get value by org.pcap4j.af.inet, use default value: 2
[main] INFO org.pcap4j.util.PropertiesLoader - [org/pcap4j/pcap4j.properties] Could not get value by org.pcap4j.af.inet6, use default value: 23
[main] INFO org.pcap4j.util.PropertiesLoader - [org/pcap4j/pcap4j.properties] Could not get value by org.pcap4j.af.packet, use default value: 17
[main] INFO org.pcap4j.util.PropertiesLoader - [org/pcap4j/pcap4j.properties] Could not get value by org.pcap4j.af.link, use default value: 18
0
[main] INFO org.pcap4j.core.Pcaps - 1 NIF(s) found.
NIF[0]: \Device\NPF_{/*not showing this stuff here */}
      : description: Microsoft
      : link layer address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX //Concealed my adress!
      : address: /192.168.192.107

Select a device number to capture packets, or enter 'q' to quit > 0    //This zero here was my personal input
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do [Remote Capture](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__remote.html)?

Pcap4J doesn't support it for now.

Comment: No, I was trying to sniff my local network. Thanks anyways, I have found a workaround! ;)

Comment: care to share? I am looking to do the same. Thanks!